# GET request to an API REST always return the index.php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, slim

I'm developing a REST api with Slim. When I use my api in localhost everything works well, but when I try to use it on my server it doesn't work well, returning the content of the index.php.

For this question I'll use the example app of Slim framework. So my index.php is:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->run();
?>
```

My folder estructure is:

```
/var/www/html/vendor/rest/
                        libs/
                            Slim
                        v1/
                            .htaccess
                            index.php
```

The .htaccess file is:

```
AddType x-mapp-php6 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php

Options -Indexes 
Options -MultiViews 
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Includes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /vendor/rest/v1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

So, when I write on Postman (for example)

http://www.mydomain.es/vendor/rest/v1/hello/jose

I get:

[image: Postman result]

When it should return

```
Hello, jose
```

I've been for a couple of days and I couldn't solve this issue. What is wrong? Maybe the .htaccess?

Comment: if memory serves me well, u are missing some php library on ur server. I don't remember which ones though

Comment: if you are using short open tag and its server setting is not enabled you'll see the same result

Comment: @slash197 could you explain in more detail. I don't understand you.

Comment: do you use short open tag anywhere in your code? `<?` instead of `<?php`

Comment: The problem is more than likely these two lines, which may be incompatible with your production host: 1) `AddType x-mapp-php6 .php` and 2) `AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php`. You may need to get rid of them. As is, your PHP files are being served as plain text files.

Comment: What kind of server are you using? Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved my question. I changed .htaccess file with this three lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now everything works properly.